# Python won't advance

Tags: python

Question: What would be the issue if python continues to ask for the same input over and over again, and won't advance to the end of the program?

```
Where do you want to go? X
And how many days will you be staying in X? 1
And how many days will you be staying in X? 2
And how many days will you be staying in X? 164
And how many days will you be staying in X? 59
...
```

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
# Import modules
import destinations
import currency

save_itinerary = True
main_function = True
while (main_function):

    # Determine length of stay
    while True:
        try:
            length_of_stay = int(input("And how many days will you be staying in " + destinations.destination[0] + "? "))
            # Check for non-positive input
            if (length_of_stay <= 0):
                print("Please enter a positive number of days.")
                continue
        except ValueError:
            print("The value you entered is invalid. Only numerical values are valid.")
            break
        else:
            break
```

Comment: It's hard to guess without code, but off the top of my head I'd check your while-loop termination conditions.

Comment: Post this section of code.

Comment: [program](http://pastebin.com/CXH3pH3z)

I will get the other two programs in a min

Comment: [Program 2](http://pastebin.com/36tKEhw9)
[Program 3](http://pastebin.com/XGAHZqRh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code is looping forever is that you have two nested `while` loops, and you never break out of the outer one. You do use `break` statements to exit the inner loop, but the condition for the outer loop is never changed, and you never execute a `break` at the right level to exit it.

Here's what I think a better version of your code would be:

```
# get rid of the outer while loop, which was never ending
while True:
    try:
        length_of_stay = int(input("And how many days will you be staying in " + destinations.destination[0] + "? "))
        if (length_of_stay <= 0):
            print("Please enter a positive number of days.")
            continue
    except ValueError:
        print("The value you entered is invalid. Only numerical values are valid.")
        # don't break here, you want to stay in the loop!
    else:
        break
```

I've used comments to indicate my changes.

You could also move the `else: break` block up and indent it so that it is attached to the `if` statement, rather than the `try`/`except` statements (and then get rid of the unnecessary `continue` statement). That's makes the flow a bit more obvious, though there's not really anything wrong with how it is now.